# Github actions disable pull request merge until certain steps completes in CI

Tags: yaml, continuous-integration, github-actions, cicd

Hi I am working on Github actions. I have separate pipeline for each induvial micro services. I have below yaml for one of the pieplien.

```
name: API

on:
  push:
      branches: [ "master" ]
      paths:
      - 'API/**'
      - ".github/workflows/api.yml"
  pull_request:
      branches: [ "master" ]
      paths:
      - 'API/**'
      - ".github/workflows/api.yml"
    
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io

jobs:
    
     build-and-push-image:
        name: "BUILD: API"
        // rest of the code
     Deploy-Dev: 
        runs-on: 'ubuntu-latest'
       //rest of the code
```

What I am expecting is Pull request should be able to merge only after if build-and-push-image step succeeds. If build step fails we should not allow to merge pull requests. So I am trying to find out any option but couldn't succeed. Can someone please help me ? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to set that up as a required check in [branch protections](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-protected-branches/managing-a-branch-protection-rule).

Comment: Hi thanks I have gone through it but couldnt locate exact section in that document, can you pls locate me to exact location

Comment: [*Creating a branch protection rule*](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-protected-branches/managing-a-branch-protection-rule#creating-a-branch-protection-rule), bullet point 7. See also [*About status checks*](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/collaborating-on-repositories-with-code-quality-features/about-status-checks).

Comment: I have gone through but i have multiple pipelines in same repo.  In status checks required Its listing jobs from all the pipelines. This option does not work for me because I have muliple pipleines and multiple PRs will get created

Comment: @BenjaminW. Lets consider I have one pipleine for Micro Service A which contains folder MicroService A. People will change content inside MicroService A and create PR. I have one yaml for Microservice A.  In yaml i have MicroService A build and deploy steps. I want to restrict PR merge until MicroService A build completes. After build succeeds merge button should be enabled for merge PR. But If I go with your words, Process will totally go wrong because your policies work based on the branch. In select If i choose any step that doesnt make sense with other pipleines

Comment: I believe you're encountering the scenario where you have a required check, but it's not always triggered, right? There's no good solution to that; the [official workaround](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-protected-branches/troubleshooting-required-status-checks#handling-skipped-but-required-checks) used to be "create a generic workflow with the same name that always succeeds", but now it's "don't use path or branch filtering on workflows for required checks".